# URL Rewrite Keeps redirecting back to xampp main page

Tags: .htaccess

I'm building a new version of a PHP website to have SEO linking URL

I'm really bad with REGEX and have very little understanding of how to work with `.htaccess` but I've been trying for two days to make a URL Rewrite rule, which I think is almost there but not quite yet.

In my `.htaccess` I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ .php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's not just rewriting the end of the URL, it's redirecting to xampp main page. Please I'm really confused because I have tried several. Don't know if it's my hosting server that's the problem.

https://localhost/new%20owolab/?id=home

here's my index page:

[image: main index page]

`````
/** Absolute path . */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

// Version
define('VERSION', '1.0.6');
// Check Version
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '<') == true) {
    exit('Please Upgrade To The Latest Version Of  PHP  From Version 5.3 + Required To Access This Site');
}

if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}
// Windows IIS Compatibility
if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace('\\', '/', substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0 - strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
    }
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'])) {
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace('\\', '/', substr(str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']), 0, 0 - strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
    }
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1);

    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = getenv('HTTP_HOST');
}

// Check if SSL
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true;
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true;
} else {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;
}



require_once "header.php";

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $filename = "layout/" . $id . '.php';
    if(file_exists($filename)){
        include $filename;
    }else{
        include "system/error.php";
    }
}else{
    include "layout/home.php";
}

require_once "footer.php";
?>````
`````

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing your efforts in question. Could you please from which URL(front end) to which URL(in back end) you want to serve, please do mention them for better understanding of question. Please add URLs in text form NOT in images or links etc.

Comment: Please add the source code in the question as a code instead of a screenshot as it is [hard to reuse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Okay..@RavinderSingh13 im trying to rewrite the front end  url

Comment: @thepunitsingh the complete code is avaliable

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you the result you need :

1. New URL
   https://localhost/new-owolab/?id=home

OR

https://localhost/newowolab/?id=home

2. Old URL
   https://localhost/new%20owolab/?id=home